# Getting double JOIN and picking correct column inside SQL query

Tags: sql, join, nested, subquery

I am trying to stick some logic into a SQL query in order to get the needed result, without having to do post-processing logic in the backend code.

Below is my query as it is now:

```
SELECT
  milestone.id,
  milestone.initiative_id,
  milestone.created,
  milestone.modified,
  status.name as "statusName",
  (COUNT(activity.id))::int as "activityCount",
  MAX(activity.end_on) AS "activityMaxEndOn",
  milestone.name,
  milestone.description,
  activity.status
FROM
  milestone
INNER JOIN
  status
ON
  status.id = milestone.status
LEFT JOIN
  activity
ON
  activity.milestone_id = milestone.id
GROUP BY
  milestone.id, status.name, activity.status
```

It returns `statusName` retrieved by JOINing `milestone` `status` on `status` table. It also returns `id` of the status for `activity` JOINed on this `milestone`. I need to:

```
- Get `status.name` for the `activity` as well, not just `id.
- Get count() of `DISTINCT` status entries from `activity` for each status
```

e.g. columns: `milestoneStatusName`, count(statusX) for each status.

Comment: whici db you are using ??

Comment: Postgres - ideally, would be nice to get a generic SQL solution e.g. not a stored procedure, but a query. If that is possible,

Comment: what  do you mean with  ::int  (this is not sql standard)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @SQL_toExecute nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Status nvarchar(100) = ''
declare @activitycount bigint = 0
declare @activityend datetime2(7)

delacre @milestoneid... etc

declare milestone_cursor cursor local static forward_only read_only
for
SELECT
  milestone.id,
  milestone.initiative_id,
  milestone.created,
  milestone.modified,
--  status.name as "statusName",
-- (COUNT(activity.id))::int as "activityCount",
--  MAX(activity.end_on) AS "activityMaxEndOn",
  milestone.name,
  milestone.description,
  activity.status
FROM
  milestone
/* INNER JOIN
  status
ON
  status.id = milestone.status
LEFT JOIN
  activity
ON
  activity.milestone_id = milestone.id
GROUP BY
  milestone.id, status.name, activity.status */

open milestone_cursor

fetch next from milestone_cursor
 into @milestoneid..etc

while @@fetchstatus = 0
begin

select @Status = status
from status where ... milestoneId?

select @activitycount = count(1)
from table where... milestoneid?


select @activityend = max(date)
from table where... milestoneid?


set @SQL_to_Execute 
= @SQL_To_Execute 
+'SELECT '
+ convert(nvarchar(100), @milestoneid) + ' as Milestone'
+ ',' + convert(nvarchar(100), @status) + ' as status'
+ ',' + convert(nvarchar(100), @activityend ) + ' as activity end'
-- continue for all columns.

+ ' Union all '


fetch next from milestone_cursor
 into @milestoneid..etc
end


close milestone_cursor
deallocate milestone_cursor

-- in the end you will have an extra ' union all '

set @sql_to_execute = left(@sql_to_execute, len(@sql_to_execute)-len(' union all '))

exec sp_msexecutesql @SQL_to_execute
```

Edit: added ',' before the select so you dont have to worry about it at the end of one.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard without seeing the schema for these tables, but if activity.status is an Id then you can just do this join:

```
INNER JOIN activity ON status.id = activity.status
```